# Float text around a figure

Tags: beamer, graphics, wrapfigure, inline, text-manipulation

I need some help from anyone of you who knows how to code in LaTex. I want to include an image in the left side of the paper and in the right remaining part I want to write some text.
I actually included the package {`wrapfig`} and wrote the code

```
\begin {wrapfigure}{l}[width=15cm]
\{includegraphicx} {its name}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

and went on writing my text, but it was appeared above the image. I watched several tutorials on Youtube, but none of them properly explains how to do this. I would really appreciate if any of you can help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  We usually ask that you provide a minimal working example (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497) so that we can see what you're actually trying.  But the command should be `\includegraphics{itsname}` (not wrapped in `{}`, and not the x at the end).  Does that fix things?  If not, please post the MWE.

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out in the comments, `\{includegraphicx} {its name}` is not a valid command and you should use `\includegraphics{filename}` instead.
Also, the width of a `wrapfigure` should go inside the last `{}`, not be specified by `[width=]`.

If you correct those mistakes, you can use `wrapfigure` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{10cm} % 15cm is usually too wide to have the figure next to text
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
        \caption{Still a very wide figure}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Rather than setting the the width to 10cm (or 15cm even), I would suggest using a relative width like `.5\linewidth`.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

[image]

Just remove the `draft`-option in the very first line.

```
\documentclass[draft]{beamer}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt \ldots
      \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{5cm}
         \includegraphics[scale=.15]{yourpicture}
         \caption{This is a caption.}
      \end{wrapfigure}
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam\ldots
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```